# Create a new View for Timekeeping data

Tags: sql, database

I have an SQL table `TBLLOGFULL` with two columns `IDuser` and `TimeCheck`.
Please help me create a new view with five columns: `IDuser`, `WorkingShift`, `WorkingDate`, `Timecheckin`, `Timecheckout`.

Table Name: TBLLOGFULL

| IDUser | TimeCheck |
| --- | --- |
| 22052939 | 2/Mar/2023 9:32:45 PM |
| 22052939 | 3/Mar/2023 6:04:52 AM |
| 22052939 | 4/Apr/2023 6:04:52 AM |
| 22052939 | 4/Apr/2023 2:04:54 PM |
| 22052939 | 4/May/2023 2:00:52 PM |
| 22052939 | 4/May/2023 10:04:54 PM |

Expected result

| UserID | WorkingDate | WorkingShift | Timecheckin | Timecheckout |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22052939 | 2/Mar/2023 | S3 | 9:32:45 PM | 6:04:52 AM |
| 22052939 | 4/Apr/2023 | S1 | 6:04:52 AM | 2:04:54 PM |
| 22052939 | 4/May/2023 | S2 | 2:00:52 PM | 10:04:54 PM |

Condition

```
IDuser = IDuser
WorkingShift =

If Min(TimeCheck) in between 5h to 7h 
       and Max(TimeCheck) in between 13h50 to 15h then Shift  = “S1”
if Min(TimeCheck) in between 13h to 15h 
       and Max(TimeCheck) in between 21h to 23h then Shift  = “S2”
If Min(TimeCheck) in between 20h to 23h 
       and Max(TimeCheck) of next Day in between 5h to 7h 
       and Max(TimeCheck) of next in Day between 5h to 7h - 
       Min(TimeCheck) in between 20h to 23h <= 9 then Shift  = “S3”

WorkingDate = Date (TimeCheck)
Timecheckin = 
If WorkingShift = "S3" then 
   If Min(TimeCheck) in between 20h to 23h else Min(TimeCheck)
Timecheckout = WorkingShift = "S3" then 
   If Max(TimeCheck) of next Day in between 5h to 7h else Max(TimeCheck)

Group by IDuser, WorkingDate
```

Expected result

```
| UserID   | WorkingDate    | WorkingShift   | Timecheckin   | Timecheckout   |
| 22052939 | 2/Mar/2023     |      S3        | 9:32:45 PM    | 6:04:52 AM     |     
| 22052939 | 4/Apr/2023     |      S1        | 6:04:52 AM    | 2:04:54 PM     |
| 22052939 | 4/May/2023     |      S2        | 2:00:52 PM    | 10:04:54 PM    |
```

Comment: Add your database, like SQL Server, MySQL ...

Comment: Hi - unfortunately this forum does not provide a free coding service so you need to show some effort at solving the problem yourself. Please update your question with the SQL that you've managed to write for yourself and then ask a specific question about an issue you are facing

Comment: Please check my Script.

Comment: What script are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem that you do not separate your goals. You need first split your task into atomic problems and then solve and debug them separately.

First thing you need to have your shifts details grouped by shift and user.
That would be something like this:

```
SELECT IDUser,        
       MIN(TimeCheck) AS TimeCheckIn
       MAX(TimeCheck) AS TimeCheckOut
FROM (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IDUser ORDER BY TimeCheck) AS rn
  FROM TBLLOGFULL
) AS t
GROUP BY IDUser,  FLOOR((rn - 1) / 2)
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
ORDER BY IDUser
```

But it works only for pairs of chronological in/outs, does not solve missing checkout etc.

Then when you have this ready you need to process the logic of WorkingShift classification, which is another task and separate problem.

https://dbfiddle.uk/zzjNbgO2